# Checkout of complete salesforce project without using the Force.com plugin

Tags: mavensmate

Need to checkout the complete project without using Force.com plugin in eclispe.
Using Sublime Text 3 and Mavensmate can we do it??

Is any other tool available ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely check out the whole project with MavensMate. When creating a project you can subscribe to whatever you want to checkout from the metadata subscription list.

There is also BrainEngine (which I'm not sure where are they up to in terms of functionality and it's paid).

Since the tooling API is out, there are probably other IDE's out there but the Force.com plugin and MM are the most used to date.